# Why doesn't MutationObserver code run on Chrome 30?

Tags: javascript, html, mutation-events, mutation, mutation-observers

From http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/02/Detect-DOM-changes-with-Mutation-Observers I got the following code:

```
var insertedNodes = [];
var observer = new WebKitMutationObserver(function(mutations) {
 alert('run');
 mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
   for (var i = 0; i < mutation.addedNodes.length; i++)
     insertedNodes.push(mutation.addedNodes[i]);
 })
});
observer.observe(document, { childList: true });
console.log(insertedNodes);

var divElement = document.createElement('div');
divElement.innerHTML = 'div element';
document.querySelector('body').appendChild(divElement);
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cUNH9

As you can see , we should see a alert because a `div` element is inserted to the DOM. But it appears MutationObserver codes don't run. How can I successfully make the MutationObserver code run?

Comment: Yes, If you observe document.body it will work..

Comment: @plalx I tried both `new MutationObserver` and `new WebKitMutationObserver`. They share same outcome.

Comment: @weilou, Do not use `document.querySelector('body')`, just use `document.body`.

Comment: @weilou See my answer...  It will work with document as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add `subTree` option as well, it should work, you want to monitor not just children of document ( `head/body`) but it's descendants as well. (And that is the reason when set to `document.body` it works).

```
observer.observe(document, {
    attributes: true,
    childList: true,
    characterData: true,
    subtree:true
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mqLkk/)**

From [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

> subtree:   Set to true if mutations to not just target, but also target's descendants are to be observed.

So what you are adding is a descendant of the `document` not its child (or direct descendant). It is a child of `body` (and that is why just mentioning `childList` and using `document.body` works). You need to mention `subTree` if you want to monitor the changes deep.

Also see the note as well:

> NOTE: At the very least, childList, attributes, or characterData must be set to true. Otherwise, "An invalid or illegal string was specified" error is thrown.

Comment: @plalx No. Subtree is required, if he wants to monitor deep in body as well, ex, if he wants to add anothe div inside this div.

Comment: @plalx check this example remove subtree and try as well. http://jsfiddle.net/9wtDc/

Comment: @PSL, Right, my bad ;)

Comment: @PSL It doesn't work in Firefox.
Is there alternative?

Comment: @cainhs MDN says it should work with firefox as well.

Comment: @PS I found the issue. I should not monitor the document.body in Firefox as the DOM is not ready. (i.e. it is empty) during page load. 

Instead, create a main div in the body and observe that. I wonder why Firefox behaves differently from Chrome and IE.